# Checkbox is checked even though checked=false

Tags: html, checkbox

I want to uncheck my Checkbox with Javascript, but it didn't work. And then I tried to set the checked property to false directly in HTML, but not even that worked: (I tried checked="false" too...)

My HTML:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="dateCheckbox" checked=false >
<label for="dateCheckbox"> Keinen Zeitraum angeben</label>
```

Result:

[image: result]

Why is it still checked?

Comment: did you test it on another browser? It could be browser's problem

Comment: and you just need to set `checked` property, if you want the checkbox to be checked

Comment: I tried it in Firefox, Chrome, Edge now, all the same ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `checked` attribute to false won't work.

If `checked` attribute is present on the `input` element, it doesn't matters what boolean value you give it, `input` element will always be checked. To make the `input` element unchecked, you have to remove the `checked` attribute.

To uncheck the checkbox input element via javascript, you can remove the `checked` attribute using `removeAttribute()` method.

Following code snippet unchecks the checkbox after 2 seconds via javascript.

```js
const checkInput = document.querySelector('#dateCheckbox');

setTimeout(() => {
  checkInput.removeAttribute('checked');
}, 2000);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="dateCheckbox" checked>
<label for="dateCheckbox"> Keinen Zeitraum angeben</label>
```

Answer (score 9):

HTML5 does not use `true` or `false` for boolean attributes. Boolean attributes are `true` by specifying the attribute name alone, and a `false` value is the omission of the attribute.

(For XHTML5, you provide the attribute-name *as the value* in order to conform to XML's rules for attributes):

---

So for an unchecked checkbox, change this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dateCheckbox" checked=false >
```

To this (HTML5 and XHTML5):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dateCheckbox">
```

---

For a checked checkbox, change this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dateCheckbox" checked=true >
```

To this (HTML5):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dateCheckbox" checked>
```

or this (XHTML5):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dateCheckbox" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkbox work this way.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="dateCheckbox" checked>
<label for="dateCheckbox"> Keinen Zeitraum angeben</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="dateCheckbox">
<label for="dateCheckbox"> Keinen Zeitraum angeben</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

It actuially doesn't matter if u have anything in `checked` only it existense does

For example,

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="dateCheckbox" checked>
<label for="dateCheckbox"> Keinen Zeitraum angeben</label>
```

But, omitting `checked` works as expected,

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="dateCheckbox">
<label for="dateCheckbox"> Keinen Zeitraum angeben</label>
```

Checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunaly, `checked` is no a boolean value (true or false). If the `checked` attribute is present in the `<input type="checkbox">` tag it will be checked, no matter what you set as value.
If you leave it out, it will work accordingly, because `checked` is not present.

Answer (score 1):

You need remove "checked" attribute to make checkbox uncheck. checked=false|true has no meaning, same as "selected" in select's options